# Use global version of object if it exists

Tags: python

I have a function that returns an API client object if it exists in a global scope or creates a new one if not:

```py
api_client = some_api.Client()

def _get_client():
    if "client" in globals():
        client = globals()["api_client"]
    else:
        client = some_api.Client()

    return client

def foo():
    client = _get_client()
    client.do_stuff()
```

This works as I expect it to, but I'm not sure if this is the correct and/or Pythonic way to do this. The use case I have is that in most cloud providers Functions-as-a-Service offerings (e.g. AWS Lambda, Google Cloud Functions) objects that are declared in the global scope can be reused across invocations of your function. This reduces the number of network connections that need to be made per request.

While I could just reference the global object in the functions that use it, it's harder to test which is why I like abstracting it behind `_get_client()`. This way the module is completely self-contained *if needed*.

That being said, I'm not entirely convinced this is a good idea or if I should go back to using the global object directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions will look into the module level scope i.e. global scope automatically when some name does not exist in the local scope. So, rather than checking in the `globals` dict, you can *ask for forgiveness*:

```
def _get_client():
    try:
        return api_client
    except NameError:
        return some_api.Client()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer a different idea, assuming your API client is never falsy, you might consider just initializing the global to `None`. Then you could do something like

```
api_client = None

def _get_client():
    return api_client or whatever_default
```